# Excel co-ordinate file to polygon shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, coordinates

So I am making a map of fishing intensity. Currently, I have an excel table with the **mid-latitude and mid-longitude** for each of my intensity data points. I also have the **c squared value** for each point on my map. As the long/lat data is the centre of each point, I want to create square polygons around this point. I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1 with an Advanced licence.

I am able to input this data as a point shapefile no problem (via add xy data), but I want to be able to show this map as a relative intensity scale using graduated colours. I can kind of do this with points, but they slightly overlap each other and it doesn't look too great (see image).

[image: What I currently have]

How can I either put this type of data in as a polygon from excel or convert my point shapefile to a polygon shapefile?

I have tried aggregate points, but it doesn't work as I don't know the distance between my points in their long/lat form. I remember being able to do this a few months ago in class, to get the figure below, but I've stupidly lost the polygon shapefile for it!

[image: What I want to achieve]

Comment: Have you tried converting your points to a rasterfile?

Comment: ...using [Point to Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/point-to-raster.htm) with for example `cell_assignment = 'SUM'`

Comment: Just tried that, don't think it worked. My raster output only gave one value in the scale range? (e.g. scale of zero to zero)

Comment: Are the points on a regularly spaced grid or irregular? Rasterization would definitely be the best idea if the former.

Comment: As an option, have you thought of a heat map?  https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/heat-mapping-in-two-simple-steps/

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert your point shapefile to polygons, simply use a Buffer and then Feature Envelope to Polygon:

[image]

This assumes that you know the spacing between the points to use as buffer distance (either standard for all of them, or based on one of their attributes), unless you don't care about possible overlaps between the polygons.